# "INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES" in Android studio 2.3 beta1with android version is "25"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-keystore

I am signing the apk with my keystore. But I am not able to install due this excepton "INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES".

Answer (score 4):

I use Android Studio to sign my app. I had been getting the same error message while installing `apk` on device.

I've solved this problem with enabling `V1 (Jar Signature)` as showed in the picture

[image]

Comment: I was tried with both signature versions jar signature and full apk signature, but I am not getting the success with the android studio 2.3 beta1. It may be support for another versions of android studio

Comment: @KonaSuresh, I am using Android Studio 2.3.1. At least for this version it helped

Answer (score 0):

try to change the Gradle tool plugin version...this solved the problem for me.
Replace classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:xxx
To classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:yyy   [to some older version]